# Use viewport for iPhone only, not iPad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, viewport, meta

I'm using the following meta tag to display a site correctly in iPhone:

`<meta name="viewport" content ="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">`

On iPad however, when using the meta viewport, the site is not correctly zoomed once loaded. Instead of showing the entire page, I have to scroll the right to see the hidden part of it. Everything looks perfect though if not the meta viewport is not used.

Is there a way to only use viewport for devices with width under 481px? Or is it possible to use CSS to archive what meta viewport does?

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.65; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

For iPad:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Comment: Thanks. What is unclear to me though is, how do I tell the browser to select either of these, depending on the device width?

Comment: You may want to include these two as iOS browser sniffer script or conditional statements using your base scripting language, which language are you coding this app, is it a native / web app? PHP, Javascript, .net etc, this has to be done before the page is served to the users browser.